# How can I adding style to react autocomplete in react js

Tags: reactjs

here is my code.Let me advice to style autocomplete component

```
 <ReactAutocomplete

 items={obj}
 shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
getItemValue={item => item.label}
renderItem={(item) =>
<div
key={item.id}>
{item.label}
</div>}
value={this.state.value}
onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })}
  onSelect={value => this.setState({ value })}
 />
```

Comment: just use classNames and customize it in the css.

Comment: I know But it's not worked. className where should I be added

Comment: please spend some time to read the documentation https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: I feel you @GuGue, className on the Autocomplete element doesn't apply it to the text input as you might expect.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
  <ReactAutocomplete   
                        ....
                            inputProps={{ style: { width: '100%',height: '100px'}, placeholder: 'test'}}  
                            wrapperStyle={{ width:  '100%'   }}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the className property right on the autocomplete element, you have to use the "inputProps" property, it's the last property in this bit of code:

```
<Autocomplete
                        getItemValue={(item) => item.label}
                        items={[
                            { id: "SPY", label: 'SPY' },
                            { id: "MSFT", label: 'MSFT' },
                            { id: "FB", label: 'FB' },
                            { id: "TSLA", label: 'TSLA' },
                        ]}
                        shouldItemRender={(item, value) => item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1}
                        renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) =>
                            <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}
                                key={item.id}>
                                {item.label}
                            </div>
                        }
                        value={this.state.symbol}
                        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ "symbol": e.target.value })}
                        onSelect={(val) => this.setState({ "symbol": val })}
                        inputProps={{ className: "form-control" }}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your renderItem prop, you can add style like this:

```
renderItem={(item) =>
<div style={{ background: 'white' }}>
  {item.label}
</div>
}
```